# How to stop auto reloading tab CHROME EXTENSION

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have chrome extension, when i open tab reload page automatically. I want that when i open tab reload page only once but code which i use reloads tab every time. i want reload once when i open tab, or go to previous tab. can someone help me please?

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
   chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id);
})
```